# How to pass params to child property in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

i am pretty new to GraphQL, getting to become a huge fan :)

But, something is not clear to me. I am using Prisma with and GraphQL-Yoga with Prisma bindings.

I do not know how to pass params from my graphQL server to sub properties. Don't know if this is clear, but i will show it with code, thats hopefully easier :)

These are my types

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  posts: [Post!]!
}

type Post {
  id: ID! @unique
  title: String!
  content: String!
  published: Boolean! @default(value: "false")
  author: User!
}
```

My schema.graphql

```
type Query {
  hello: String
  posts(searchString: String): [Post]
  users(searchString: String, searchPostsTitle: String): [User]
  me(id: ID): User
}
```

and my users resolver:

```
import { Context } from "../../utils";

export const user = {
  hello: () => "world",
  users: (parent, args, ctx: Context, info) => {
    return ctx.db.query.users(
      {
        where: {
          OR: [
            {
              name_contains: args.searchString
            },
            {
              posts_some: { title_contains: args.searchPostsTitle }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      info
    );
  },
  me: (parent, args, ctx: Context, info) => {
    console.log("parent", parent);
    console.log("args", args);
    console.log("info", info);
    console.log("end_________________");
    return ctx.db.query.user({ where: { id: args.id } }, info);
  }
};
```

and my posts resolver

```
import { Context } from "../../utils";

export const post = {
  posts: (parent, args, ctx: Context, info) => {
    return ctx.db.query.posts(
      {
        where: {
          OR: [
            {
              title_contains: args.searchString
            },
            {
              content_contains: args.searchString
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      info
    );
  }
};
```

so, now :)

I am able to do the following when i am in the GraphQL playground on my prisma service:

```
{
  user(where: {id: "cjhrx5kaplbu50b751a3at99d"}) {
    id
    name
    posts(first: 1, after: "cjhweuosv5nsq0b75yc18wb2v") {
      id
      title
      content
    }
  }
}
```

but i cant do it on the server, if i do something like that.. i am getting the error:

```
"error": "Response not successful: Received status code 400"
```

this is what i am trying:

```
{
  me(id: "cjhrx5kaplbu50b751a3at99d") {
    id
    name
    posts(first:1) {
      id
      title
      content
    }
  }
}
```

does somebody know how i could do that?

Comment: ok.. i solved it :) sometimes it just needs thinking when writing and explaining it here.. i will leave the question for other people having same issue..

Answer (score 1):

since i have a custom type of user, posts does not have params like the generated one. Either i am using the the generated one, or modifying it to look like this:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts(where: PostWhereInput, orderBy: PostOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [Post!]
}
```

EDIT 2018 June 4th

```
# import Post from './generated/prisma.graphql'

type Query {
  hello: String
  posts(searchString: String): [Post]
  users(searchString: String, where: UserWhereInput, orderBy: UserOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [User]
  me(id: ID): User
}

type Mutation {
  createUser(name: String!): User
  createPost(
    title: String!
    content: String!
    published: Boolean!
    userId: ID!
  ): Post
}
```

I copied the params over from prisma.graphql manually.

Comment: Can you also share the new `schema.graphql`? You need to import the types from the new arguments :)

Comment: Yes! Note that `UserWhereInput`, `UserOrderByInput` and `User` are imported "transitively" from the `import Post` statement in the first lien :)